# getting checked value from checkbox thats taking data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox, checked

I have problem to get to the checked value in checkbox.
I have first query that is taking names of the tables in database and second query that is taking names of the columns of that tables. Names of the columns are displayed in a checkbox, but i have problem to take that values from the checkbox. I know I should use $_POST['kolona'] but somehow that variable its not recognized:

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error: Greška u konekciji";
    exit;
}

$sql1 = "SHOW TABLES FROM db_baza";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);


if (!$result1) 
{
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}



while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1))
{
    echo  "<div id='blok' style='width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red;margin:20px;float:left;'>{$row1[0]}"."</br>"; 
    $tablename=$row1[0];

    $sql2="SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '{$tablename}'";
    $result2= mysql_query($sql2);

    while($row2=mysql_fetch_row($result2))
    echo "<form id='forma1' action='' method='POST'><input type='checkbox' name='kolona[]' value='{$row2[0]}' />{$row2[0]}</br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='{$tablename}'/></form>";
    echo "</div>";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
if(isset($_POST['kolona'])
    echo 1;
?>
```

So, I am just trying to echo number one, i will need it for other stuff but just for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify these lines:

```
echo "<form id='forma1' action='' method='POST'>";
while($row2=mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='kolona[]' value='{$row2[0]}' />{$row2[0]}</br>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='{$tablename}'/></form>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Its not working, i have an syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), on line where its echo for the form: echo "<form id='forma1' action='' method='POST'>";

Comment: ok, so i changed last three lines in my code with:          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if(isset($_POST['kolona']))
                {
                    1;
                }
        } and now its working, whatever, still not sure why but thanks for help Deepak!